# javascript escape colon and number with backtick in dynamic content

Tags: javascript

I need to escape the colon : in javascript function that create dynamic content.

```
    ${Result.map( item => `<li><img src="${item._embedded.wp:featuredmedia[0].source_url}" alt="${item.title.rendered}"></li>`).join('')}`);
```

The JSON that i need to convert, contain the colon and number ( wp:featuredmedia ) and this error cause an issue. How i can escape the colon and number ( [0] )  with backtick ?

Comment: So you want to convert `item._embedded.wp:featuredmedia[0].source_url` to `item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url` ?

Comment: Yes! whit this item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url work! thanks